# Mysql trigger failes

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, exists, create-table

I have a table that gets updated quite often, so I want to log the modifications.

To log the modifications, I want to create a MySQL trigger. My first attempt worked but I'm not so happy with the result. There is a hole in trigger. Here is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `test`$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `test`.`logger_insert`
AFTER INSERT ON `test`.`foo`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT INTO logger(id, status, modified, type) 
VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.status, NOW(), NEW.type);


END$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `test`.`logger_update`
AFTER UPDATE ON `test`.`foo`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT INTO logger(id, status, modified, type) 
VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.status, NOW(), NEW.type);


END$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `test`.`logger_delete`
AFTER DELETE ON `test`.`foo`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT INTO logger(id, status, modified, type) 
VALUES (OLD.id, 'Erased', NOW(), OLD.type);

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The problem is that I can't update, insert or delete the table `foo` if somebody decides to drop the table `logger`.

I tried to `CREATE TABLE logger` if it doesn't exist inside of the trigger without any success. `INSERT IGNORE` didn't work either.

How shall I solve this problem if someone accidentally dumps the `logger` table?

Comment: Tell them to not drop random tables in your database. Its the same if someone accidentally drops your main table.

Comment: change password for `root` ;P and revoke permission for that table ;P